# Who/what is creating /dev/loop0, /dev/loop1, ... /dev/loop7?

Tags: systemd, udev, devices, loop-device

I've recently been working on a project requiring encrypted files mounted via a connection to a loop device. While the project will run on an Ubuntu system, I was experimenting with setting it up on my Arch Linux workstation. That's when I noticed that Arch doesn't have any loop devices initialized by default, while all the Ubuntu systems I checked (ranging from 18.04 to 22.10) always have 8 pre-created loop devices. This kind of makes sense, since you need elevated privileges to run

```
losetup -f
```

On the other hand, the permissions on /dev/loopN don't allow ordinary users to use them anyway. But in any case I can't figure out who/what is creating these devices. I've looked over the udev rules in **/lib/udev/rules.d**, and couldn't find anything relevant.  I also looked through the systemd service files in **/lib/systemd/system** and couldn't find anything there, either. This is mostly a curiosity question, as I hate magical events in my operating systems.

**Here is the evidence that there are no snaps mounted on this system**

```
root@texas-tea:~# ls /dev/loop*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop2  /dev/loop4  /dev/loop6  /dev/loop-control
/dev/loop1  /dev/loop3  /dev/loop5  /dev/loop7
```

```
root@texas-tea:~# lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                          8:1    0   714M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                          8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                          8:5    0 237.8G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt                253:0    0 237.8G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgtexas--tea-root       253:1    0  47.7G  0 lvm   /
    ├─vgtexas--tea-swap_1     253:2    0   3.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─vgtexas--tea-var        253:3    0  23.9G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─vgtexas--tea-var+condor 253:4    0   952M  0 lvm   /var/condor
    ├─vgtexas--tea-tmp        253:5    0  11.9G  0 lvm   /tmp
    └─vgtexas--tea-var+local  253:6    0 149.7G  0 lvm   /var/local
sr0                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
root@texas-tea:~# mount | grep loop
root@texas-tea:~#
```

```
root@texas-tea:~# losetup -l
root@texas-tea:~#
```

---

EDIT: I recently became aware that loop devices can be created as a compile time option or passed as a kernel parameter (see max_loop= here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)
Checking /etc/default/[grub|grub.d] I don't see anything related being passed as a kernel parameter on boot, so my current best guess is that the Ubuntu kernel compilers are setting BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT=8 in the build configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In particular, checking the 18.04 machine I use in the office there are the usual 8 loop devices, but `losetup -a` doesn't show any of them being in use.

Comment: Seems like perhaps you missed the point of that duplicate.

Comment: Please explain.  It's not a duplicate, or even a related question.  There are mounted snaps on the 22.10 machine I checked but none on the 18.04 machine.

Comment: The most common explanation by far is the presence of snap packages, hence the duplicate. If there are mysterious loop-mounts *without* snaps on the 18.04 machine, then edit your question to show appropriate lsblk and df and snapd output. We will need those clues.

Comment: Please include some evidence. If you want this to be reopened, please list output of the commands `lsblk` and `losetup -l` in your question.

Comment: I mean, it's likely that the snap package is somehow responsible for the creation of these unused loop devices, but I would like to know how. I do not appreciate magical things happening on my linux machines which is why I use Arch linux whenever possible.  Unfortunately this isn't an option at work.  I've edited my original question to demonstrate there are no snaps mounted on the machine.

Comment: What was the installation process for setting up this snap-less Ubuntu system? Without knowing how to reproduce this, it's hard to tell you where to look for the cause. As for magical things happening... I have an Arch Linux with `% ls /dev/loop*` => 
`/dev/loop0  /dev/loop1  /dev/loop2  /dev/loop3  /dev/loop4  /dev/loop5  /dev/loop6  /dev/loop7  /dev/loop-control` and without snap installed. I'd guess this is just from [the `loop` module being loaded at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554445/70524).

Answer (score -1):

Type `lsblk` (or even `df`) and you will see "who/what is creating" these devices :)

These loop devices are mount points for installed snap packages. Each snap package uses one device.

Comment: No, loop devices are not mountpoints, they are devices that get mounted and you can see their mountpoints (which are usually folders) when you type `lsblk`. The mounts are created by systemd and you can find the correspondig `.mount`-files in `/etc/systemd/system`.

Comment: @mook765  Unfortunately I can't find *any* .mount files in /etc/systemd/system.  `find . -depth -iname \*.mount` returns nothing.

Comment: @raj As pointed out by mook765, loop devices are not mountpoints, nor are they block devices.  They don't show up in `lslbk` unless you bind them to something.  For example, if I run `losetup /dev/loop0 my-file-to-mount.img` loop0 will show up in lsblk.  When I run lsblk on the ubuntu systems I'm looking at, no loop devices show up in `lsblk` indicating they're not bound to anything.

Comment: This obviously isn't the case here...